# Magento2: user magnifier widget without fotorama

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, gallery, fotorama-slider

I am developing a custom theme for Magento 2.1.x based on blank theme.
In the product view page, I want to get rid of the fotorama gallery (the images are as normal img tag, ne after another.
What I would like to do is to use the magnifier function in a way taht when a user clicks on the img tag the nagnifier overlay is shown.

Is there a way to do it without using fotorama?

Comment: Are you referring to any zoom plugin or specifically the one that comes with Fotorama?

Comment: the one that comes with fotorama

Comment: have you found any solution ?